# Multiple Software Install with one install via USB

Tags: windows-7, cmd, usb, installation, windows-installer

I want to create a USB that I can plug into a machine (windows 7) and run one install package that will install multiple.

ok I have A.exe and B.exe

I want to bundle these 2 installation files into a single un-attended installation file [C.exe].

And when I run the C.exe it should install the above applications.

Any ideas how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bundle installer. [Burn from Wix](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2009/7/14/lets-talk-about-burn) is the best free option. There are other tools that can do this without scripting, thus much easy for you, but you need to purchase a license for those.